# Second IF Function Isn't Executing in SetInterval Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, authentication

So, I'm working on a simple sign up page, and right now, I'm working on a system that recognizes and displays when you are using illegal chars in your password or username.

It works great, but it's only executing the part about the illegal chars in the username, and not the password. Which is strange, since if I comment out the illegal chars username `if` function, the password `if` function works just fine!

Here's my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var errorThere2 = false;
  var errorThere = false;
  setInterval(function() {
    if ((/^[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]+$/.test($("#usernameBox").val())) || $("#usernameBox").val() == "") {
      currentText = "";
      errorThere2 = false;
      $("#usernameBox").css("border", "2px solid #707070");
      $("#submitButton").attr("disabled", false);
      $("#wrongStuff").html(currentText);
    } else {
      if (errorThere2 == false) {
        var currentText = $("#wrongStuff").text();
        var addedText = "Usernames are limitied to a-z, A-Z, and 0-9! ";
        $("#wrongStuff").html(currentText + addedText);
        errorThere2 = true;
      }
      $("#submitButton").attr("disabled", true);
      $("#usernameBox").css("border", "2px solid #E90B0B");
    }
    // Test for password box
    if (/^[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!@#$%^{}-&*()`~'"<>,.?_=+]+$/.test($("#passwordBox").val()) || $("#passwordBox").val() == "") {
      currentText = "";
      errorThere = false;
      $("#passwordBox").css("border", "2px solid #707070");
      $("#submitButton").attr("disabled", false);
      $("#wrongStuff").html(currentText);
    } else {
      if (errorThere == false) {
        var currentText = $("#wrongStuff").text();
        var addedText = "Passwords cannot include the characters |, \\, or []! ";
        $("#wrongStuff").html(currentText + addedText);
        errorThere = true;
      }
      $("#submitButton").attr("disabled", true);
      $("#passwordBox").css("border", "2px solid #E90B0B");
    }
  }, 100);
  var hoveredOver = false;
  $(".enterButton").mouseenter(function() {
    if (hoveredOver === false) {
      $(this).css("background", "#F056AD");
      hoveredOver = true;
    }
  });
  $(".enterButton").mouseleave(function() {
    if (hoveredOver === true) {
      $(this).css("background", "#56E0F0");
      hoveredOver = false;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Sign Up</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="icon" href="logo.png">
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <br>
    <div id="mainTitle">Sign Up</div><br><br><br><br><br>
    <center>
      <form method="POST" action="signup">
        <p id="wrongStuff" style="color: red;"></p><br>
        <input class="enterText" id="nameBox" required name="nameBox" type="text" placeholder="Full name"><br><br>
        <input class="enterText" id="usernameBox" required name="usernameBox" type="text" placeholder="Username"><br><br>
        <input class="enterText" id="emailBox" required name="emailBox" spellcheck="false" type="email" placeholder="Email Address"><br><br>
        <input class="enterText" id="passwordBox" required name="passwordBox" type="password" placeholder="Password"><br><br>
        <input class="enterText" id="passwordBox2" required name="passwordBox2" type="password" placeholder="Repeated password"><br><br><br>
        <input class="enterButton" id="submitButton" type="submit" value="Submit">
      </form>
    </center>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Just so you know, the allowed chars for the username are a-z, A-Z, and 0-9 and passwords are a-z, A-Z, 0-9, and most other symbols (excluding a few like \ and | which would cause errors with other parts of my program)

Comment: Your code makes very little sense. Why are you using a timeout to check the values in the fields every 100ms instead of an `input` event? Secondly, you can apply the styling to the elements on hover using CSS alone which will perform better. Thirdly your snippet is clearly broken, so I'm not even sure why you believe that any part of this is working correctly.

Comment: You should try using first if username exists in database...with an Ajax request. In this same request veryfy in php allowed characters...this is a valid ` preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9-_.@#]*$/",$username)  ` you can use in ajax